# PHP: Parsing a text line to get its words as parameters

Tags: php

I need develope a function that is able to read a text line and get its words numerically.
For example:

```
$textline ="this is an example line";

function parameter($text,$number);
{???}
```

So i could call:

```
parameter($textline,0); //returns "this"
parameter($textline,3); //returns "example
```

Any help is more than appreciated since lot of years without programming in PHP and i am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7 you can use the `explode()` function as explained in the following example:

```php
<?php
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

function parameter($text, $number){

$pieces = explode(" ", $text);
return $pieces[$number];

}

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution. It would be work only if every word is separated from others by space(" ").

```
function parameter($text, $number)
{
    $parameters = explode(" ", $text);
    return $parameters[$number];
}
```